# OCSInventory handover table and form

Tags: monitoring, database-administration, sysadmin

I need to make some kind of handover table.

Records would look like this:

PC , user , action , date;

X , Y , return , 10.07;

X , Z , hire , 11.07;

A , Y , hire , 16.07;

etc. Each record would generate handover-form which would be printed and signed by admin and user.

Is it even possible? If it is - how to get to it :/ ?

Comment: That would be a great question to ask your admin, rather than the internet. Because yes it is (of course) possible, but there are so many possible solutions that your problem is impossible to answer well;  especially when you want (and you should) integrate with existing procedures and systems, such as asset management system to avoid duplicating information.

Comment: Records in the table would have been manually entered - that's why it doesn't matter what procedures are up in office. I am just intern - i don't know anything about network procedures here so it should be easiest solution that actually exists. My admin doesn't actually know exactly how to do it - that's why it is intern's task :D